# How to pass a filename by drag-and-drop to a shortcut in Windows

Tags: windows, shortcuts, command-line-arguments

I have a program `program.exe` and a document `document.txt`, and to open the document, I can drag `document.txt` onto `program.exe`. So far so good. Now I want to call it with a command-line parameter `-param` so that the full command line is `program.exe -param document.txt` Unfortunately, I can't do this with drag and drop, so I need to fire up cmd and type in the command manually. This takes too long, and I need an easier way.

How can I create a shortcut that I can drop the file onto, and have it call the program with the command-line parameter?

I tried setting the shortcut to `program.exe -param "%1"`, but that didn't work, because it tried to open the file `%1`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use `program.exe -param` as a target in your shortcut. Document path (or whatever else you drop onto it) is appended by default.

Loosely related: You may also drop an item from explorer onto command line window - this may save you a lot of typing!

Answer (score 3):

Make a batch file that'd call your target executable with `-param` and batch file's first parameter and then make shortcut point to that batch file.

Comment: You can simply drag files on batch files aswell, they will be passed as quoted paths the same way - however, since the batch file is no longer run in the directory it is stored in, you may want to `CD %~dp0` at the start of it to switch to the batch directory first.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get it to work with a regular shortcut, but you might want to create a batch file instead. Use `%1` in place of where you want the dropped file's path. E.g.:

```
"C:\path to utility\myUtility.exe" %1 -f -g
```